# Add columns dynamically based on selection in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, dashboard

I am currently working on a mini project in Angular 7.

I need to have a table or pivot table that can render columns dynamically based on a prior selection of filters.

This is the sample filter:

```
brands = [
    { id: 1, brand: 'Audi' },
    { id: 2, brand: 'BMW' },
    { id: 3, brand: 'Benz' }
    ]
```

This is a  fictitious data array:

```
car_data = [
    { brand: 'Audi', model: 'Q3', fuel_eff: 12.5, fuel_tank: 65 },
    { brand: 'Audi', model: 'R8', fuel_eff: 6.0, fuel_tank: 60 },
    { brand: 'Audi', model: 'A4', fuel_eff: 13.0, fuel_tank: 65 },
    { brand: 'BMW', model: 'M3', fuel_eff: 9.0, fuel_tank: 65 },
    { brand: 'BMW', model: '740i', fuel_eff: 13, fuel_tank: 75 },
    { brand: 'BMW', model: '320i', fuel_eff: 14, fuel_tank: 65 },
    { brand: 'Benz', model: 'CLA', fuel_eff: 12.0, fuel_tank: 65 },
    { brand: 'Benz', model: 'GLA', fuel_eff: 14.0, fuel_tank: 65 },
    { brand: 'Benz', model: 'S350L', fuel_eff: 12.0, fuel_tank: 85 },
    { brand: 'Benz', model: 'S500L', fuel_eff: 12.0, fuel_tank: 85 }
    ]
```

What I have currently achieved:
I have a dashboard that shows the all of the data, and the user needs to select the brands he/she wants to see. Then the data be filtered and rendered accordingly on the dashboard. I managed to filter data based on single and multiple selections.

My current challenge is on how do I dynamically add more columns for each brand?
For example, if I selected 'BMW', the columns are 'brand', 'model', 'fuel_eff', 'fuel_tank'.
Now if I selected both 'BMW' and 'Audi', I want to see the last 3 columns above for EACH brand. Maybe something like:

```
BMW                            AUDI
model  fuel_eff  fuel_tank     model   fuel_eff   fuel_tank
M3     9.0       65            A4      13.0       60
```

I have created  a sample app with the data which isnt quite complete - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkhdnc

Appreciate any inputs or links to relevant materials.
Thanks!

Comment: You can try using templates based on number of brands selected

Answer (score 0):

```
//HTML
  <ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="TemplateName;context:{modelsArray: modelsArray}"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
<ng-template #SingleBrand let-modelsArray="modelsArray">
  <div>Single Brand HTML</div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #MultiBrand let-modelsArray="modelsArray">
  <div>Multi Brand HTML</div>    
</ng-template>

//TS
@ViewChild(SingleBrand, { static: true }) SingleBrand: TemplateRef<any>;
@ViewChild(MultiBrand , { static: true }) MultiBrand : TemplateRef<any>;
```

Comment: what is this modelsArray doing? the data array, which in this example would be car_data?

Comment: This can be replaced by car_data

Comment: This is not a solution.. it is just an concept that may fit your case